# remove an element from a singly sorted linked list C++

Tags: c++

I have a sorted linked list and im trying to create a function to delete whatever the user passes to nameToSearch. but i keep geting an error. Below is what i have so far

```
void deleteProduct(NodePtr head, char* nameToSearch)
    {
        NodePtr nodeUnderEdit = findNodeByName(head, nameToSearch);
        if (nodeUnderEdit == NULL) 
        {
            cout<<"\n ERROR: Product not found \n";
        }
        else
        {

            delete nodeUnderEdit;
            nodeUnderEdit = nodeUnderEdit->next;

        }   

    }
```

Comment: If your list is singly linked, then `find` should return a pointer to the element *just before* the found element.

Comment: Think hard about what nodeUnderEdit is pointing to shortly (very shortly) after that `delete` operator.

Comment: @KerrekSB +1 or return the *address* of the pointer that is referencing the node in question and modify that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  delete nodeUnderEdit;
  nodeUnderEdit = nodeUnderEdit->next;
```

If you delete `nodeUnderEdit` first, then `nodeUnderEdit->next` will be lost.
You need to first make sure that the node that before nodeUnderEdit's next is connected to `nodeUnderEdit->next`, then you can do the remove.

Comment: so i need a temp to store nodeUnderEdit->next and then assign the temp back to nodeUnderEdit. right?

Comment: @user1896464 you need to remember the node that is before nodeUnderEdit, assume it is A, you should first do A->next = nodeUnderEdit->next, then you can delete nodeUnderEdit safely.

Comment: Thats what ive been trying to do but Since i cant have a previous in a singly linked list, im having a hard time coming up with a way to store the previous.

Comment: @user1896464 when you find the nodeUnderEdit, you basically iterate over the list, so when you are at node A, you check whether A-> next is the nodeUnderEdit, if yes, then you label A as previous node of nodeUnderEdit. make sense?

Comment: please take a look at the new code i just added in the original post. im still getting runtime errors.

Comment: @user1896464 why you do: NodePtr tmp = head; ?

Comment: oh it should be current not head...typo

Comment: im still getting the error. im confused as to what im doing wrong

Comment: @user1896464 Please see this link: which has good explanation with figures: http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/09/29/programming-interview-questions-5-linkedlist-remove-nodes/

Answer (score 2):

This is always a problem with a singly-linked list.

The problem arises because deleting the current node from a linked list requires modifying the pointer in the *previous* node -- to which you don't have direct access.

One way to handle this is to use a list with a sentinel (a final node containing a value you recognize as the end of the list). In this case, you can copy the value from the *next* node into the current node, then delete the next node from the list.

Comment: I like this answer as well as @Nathans; it goes further than just the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an item in a singly linked list you must change the pointer from the Previous record to point to the Next record. It is not sufficient for your "findNodeByName" to just find the node with the matching name. It must find the node Previous to it in the sort order, then set the Next pointer of that record of the Next point of the record to be deleted. Only after you have updated the Next pointer of the Previous record can you delete the record you searched for.